# FFMPEG subtitle: mov_text removal

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle

I have problems with subtitles. My video playout can not play them. So I have been trying to remove it.

```
C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\eclipse\workspace\tvpohoda_archiv>"c:\\lib/ffmpeg/bin/ffm
peg.exe" -i "videa/1050028-CITRON_-_Uz_zavrate_ridnou_c.m4v"  -sn -c:a copy -c:v
 copy  "videa/1050028-CITRON_-_Uz_zavrate_ridnou_c2.mov"
ffmpeg version N-57650-gcb52d6d Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 30 2013 20:35:46 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 48.100 / 52. 48.100
  libavcodec     55. 39.100 / 55. 39.100
  libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'videa/1050028-CITRON_-_Uz_zavrate_ridno
u_c.m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1
    encoder         : Lavf55.19.104
  Duration: 00:04:56.49, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 7239 kb/s
    Chapter #0.0: start 0.000000, end 296.400000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576 [
SAR 212:225 DAR 53:45], 6997 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 24
0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
File 'videa/1050028-CITRON_-_Uz_zavrate_ridnou_c2.mov' already exists. Overwrite
 ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mov, to 'videa/1050028-CITRON_-_Uz_zavrate_ridnou_c2.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1
    encoder         : Lavf55.19.104
    Chapter #0.0: start 0.021000, end 296.421000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 212
:225 DAR 53:45], q=2-31, 6997 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, 240 kb/s
 (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 7408 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=  262031kB time=00:04:56.49 bitrate=7239.9kbits
/s
video:253116kB audio:8700kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.0820
40%
```

Or:

```
C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\eclipse\workspace\tvpohoda_archiv>"c:\\lib/ffmpeg/bin/ffm
peg.exe" -i "videa/1050028-CITRON_-_Uz_zavrate_ridnou_c.m4v"  -map 0:0 -map 0:1
-c:a copy -c:v copy  "videa/1050028-CITRON_-_Uz_zavrate_ridnou_c2.mov"
ffmpeg version N-57650-gcb52d6d Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 30 2013 20:35:46 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 48.100 / 52. 48.100
  libavcodec     55. 39.100 / 55. 39.100
  libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'videa/1050028-CITRON_-_Uz_zavrate_ridno
u_c.m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1
    encoder         : Lavf55.19.104
  Duration: 00:04:56.49, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 7239 kb/s
    Chapter #0.0: start 0.000000, end 296.400000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576 [
SAR 212:225 DAR 53:45], 6997 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 24
0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
Output #0, mov, to 'videa/1050028-CITRON_-_Uz_zavrate_ridnou_c2.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1
    encoder         : Lavf55.19.104
    Chapter #0.0: start 0.021000, end 296.421000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 212
:225 DAR 53:45], q=2-31, 6997 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, 240 kb/s
 (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 2702 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=   95498kB time=00:01:48.03 bitrate=7241.6kbits/
frame= 4436 fps=4435 q=-1.0 size=  157319kB time=00:02:57.38 bitrate=7265.2kbits
frame= 6296 fps=4196 q=-1.0 size=  223194kB time=00:04:11.77 bitrate=7262.0kbits
frame= 7408 fps=4121 q=-1.0 Lsize=  262031kB time=00:04:56.49 bitrate=7239.9kbit
s/s
video:253116kB audio:8700kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.0820
40%
```

But it did not worked, subtitles have stayed there.

i am normally starting this ffmpeg from java but this files are from command line

Please can you help me?

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. I am starting ffmpeg from my java application.
you can fine complete files here:
[using -sn](http://www.tvrebel.cz/subory/sn.txt) [using -map](http://www.tvrebel.cz/subory/map.txt)
but subtitles still remain there
Thanks again for help

Comment: The console outputs indicate that neither of the output files contain subtitles.

Comment: Hi yes. but after translation. Subtitles are still there. This size is 0. But record about them is still there

Comment: Are you sure you're playing the correct output files? The outputs from the `ffmpeg` commands you showed should not contain subtitles at all, so I'm guessing the problem is not with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Hi, yes I am, I have done thousands of videos with FFMPEG, this have never happened. you can try [video link](http://www.tvrebel.cz/subory/1050028-CITRON_-_Uz_zavrate_ridnou_c.m4v)

Comment: Hi, i have found 3, there are probably more in our database, I am just putting down songs/video what have not played properly on playout

Comment: @user3461178, did you ever find a solution to this? I also have some MP4s that FFMPEG refuses to strip subtitles from.

Comment: Hi, I have not with FFMPEG, There is also MLT framework (melt) online, and that have solved my problem. Thanks for asking. Later I have found an idea how it can be done with FFMPEG and pipes / convert video to raw use pipe so second ffmpeg an convert it back to MP4

Comment: @user3461178 - So I revisited this issue after 18 months, and I found a solution. I noticed all the videos I had issues with had something in common; they all had chapters. So I stripped chapters from my input source, using `-map_chapters -1`, and the stubborn subtitle stream was no more! I'm not entirely sure what the connection between chapters and subtitle stream is, but if you don't need chapters, this may help.